# A problem in single variable calculus

Tags: calculus, problem-solving

Given a function $a(t)$, and the condition $$\dot{a}^2 \geq 1 - \frac{a^2}{L^2} $$ and $$a(t) \leq L $$ I need to prove that if there exists a $t_0$ such that $\dot{a}(t_0)<0$ and $a(t_0)>0$, $a(t)$ is eventually zero that is there exists a $\tilde{t}$ such that $a(\tilde{t})=0$. Now from intuition as the lower bound gets bigger, it seems $\dot{a}$ gets more negative. Now when trying to put these in equations the first step I am attempting is that for any $t_1>t_0$, I am trying to show $\dot{a}(t_1)<\dot{a}(t_0)$. But that doesn't seem to follow from the given inequality that I am allowed to use. I thought if I took $t_1=t_0 +dt$ I would get some information about $\ddot{a}$. Any leads on how to go about this?

Answer (score 1):

Either I am missing something, or this is not necessarily true.

Let $a(t) = t^2 + 1$, $L = 1$.

$$
\dot{a}^2 + \frac{a^2}{L^2} = (2t)^2 + (t^2 + 1)^2 \geq 1
$$

At $t_0 < 0$:

$$
\begin{cases}
\dot{a}(t_0) = 2t_0 < 0 \\
a(t_0) = t_0^2 + 1 > 0
\end{cases}
$$

But $a(t)$ is always greater than zero.

### UPDATE

With the new condition, $a(t) \leq L$, it's actually provable, assuming $a$ is differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$.

#### Case $\exists t' : a(t') < 0$

Since $a$ is differentiable, it's continuous. $a(t_0) > 0$, $a(t') < 0$. The [intermediate value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem) applied to $t_0$ and $t'$ implies $\exists \tilde{t} : a(\tilde{t}) = 0$.

#### Case $\forall t : a(t) \geq 0$

Note that the differential condition as written implies $L \neq 0$.

$$a \leq L \implies L > 0 \land \frac{a}{L} \leq 1$$

Now let's have a look at the first inequality again.

$$\dot{a}^2 \geq 1 - \frac{a^2}{L^2} \iff \dot{a}^2 + \frac{a^2}{L^2} \geq 1 \implies \left ( \dot{a}(t) = 0 \implies a(t) = L \right )$$

We know that $\exists t_0 : \dot{a}(t_0) < 0$. If $\exists t_1 : \dot{a}(t_1) = 0$ then $t_1 < t_0$ — otherwise select $\alpha = \operatorname{argmin}(\{a(t) : t_0 \leq t \leq t_1\})$, by the [extreme value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_value_theorem) $\dot{a}(\alpha) = 0 \implies a(\alpha) = L \implies \forall t \in [t_0, t_1] \, a(t) = L \implies \dot{a}(t_0) \not< 0$, contradiction. Note that due to [Darboux's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_%28analysis%29#Darboux's_theorem) $\dot{a}$ cannot become positive without going through $0$.

#### Unboundedness

So $\forall t \geq t_0 \, \dot{a}(t) < 0$, the last problem we could have is $a$ being limited below. Let $M > 0$ be the lower bound. By [Weierstrass's theorem](https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=auto&tl=en&u=https%3A%2F%2Fru.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2F%D0%A2%D0%B5%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D0%92%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%88%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B0_%D0%BE%D0%B1_%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8) $lim_{t \to \infty} a(t) = M$, or $\forall \epsilon > 0 \, \exists \delta \, \forall t > \delta \, |a(t) - M| < \epsilon$.

$$
\dot{a} \leq -\sqrt{1 - \frac{a^2}{L^2}} \leq -\sqrt{1 - \frac{(M + \epsilon)^2}{L^2}} = -C
$$

By the [mean value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem) $a(t + 1) - a(t) = \dot{a}(\gamma) \leq -C \implies a(t) - C \geq a(t + 1)$, therefore $a(t + \left\lceil \frac{L}{C} \right\rceil + \ldots) < 0$, which brings us to the first case again.

#### Conclusion

To give an example, consider $a(t) = \sin(t)$ and $L = 1$.

$$
\begin{cases}
(cos(t))^2 + \frac{(sin(t))^2}{1^2} \geq 1 \\
sin(t) \leq 1
\end{cases}
$$

At $t_0$ in the second quarter $\sin(t_0) > 0$ and $\cos(t_0) < 0$, also $\sin(0) = 0$.

Comment: There seems to be nothing wrong with your example. I came across this as a statement in a physics textbook, and I was pretty sure it translated into this. I will check if I have missed some condition that would exclude your counter-example but the counter-example certainly helps.

Comment: One difference that I had missed and now have added is that $a(t) \leq L$. Your example then gets excluded. But I don't know what this would lead to.

Comment: I believe it makes it provable, check out the update.

Comment: Hey Pavel, I am trying to follow your arguments and lost you a bit at the second point. If there $\exists$ a $t_1: \dot{a}(t_1)=0$ then $t_1<t_0$. Are you saying this is true for sure? If yes then why so? If you're not saying that and instead  saying that either $t_1<t_0$ or there exists an $\alpha\in [t_0,t_1]$ such that $\dot{a}(\alpha)=0$ then I don't get why should there exist such an $\alpha$. The extreme value theorem says that in $[t_0,t_1]$, there will be some $\tilde{t}$ such that $a(\tilde{t})\geq a(t)$ $\forall t \in[t_0,t_1]$. I don't get how that implies the existence of $\alpha$.

Comment: This is true for sure. If there was such $t_1 > t_0$ that $\dot{a}(t_1) = 0$, we could consider $[t_0; t_1]$ -- this is a closed interval, $a$ is continuous, so by the extreme value theorem there exists a point $\alpha$ in which $a$ reaches its minimum on $[t_0; t_1]$. $\alpha$ is an extremum, so $\dot{a}(\alpha) = 0$. But we know that if $\dot{a}(t) = 0$ then $a(t) = L$, so the minimum of $a$ on $[t_0; t_1]$ is the same as the maximum (coming from $a \leq L$), which means that $\forall t \in (t_0; t_1] \, a(t) = L$, therefore $\dot{a}(t_0) \not< 0$ (one-sided limit is $0$), contradiction.

Comment: But what if in $[t_0,t_1]$, $a$ decreases monotonically, in that case the extreme value theorem will not imply the extremum $\alpha$, but instead pick out $a(t_0)$ to be the absolute minimum.

Comment: Let $\dot{a}(t_0) = y < 0$. $\forall \epsilon > 0 \, \exists \delta(\epsilon) > 0 \, \forall t : 0 < |t - t_0| < \delta \, \left | \frac{a(t) - a(t_0)}{t - t_0} - y \right | < \epsilon$. Consider $\epsilon = - \frac{y}{2}$. In this case $\exists x \in (t_0, \min(t_0 + \delta(-\frac{y}{2}), t_1)) : a(x) < a(t_0)$. $a(x) < a(t_0) \leq L \implies a(x) < a(t_1) = L$. So the minimum is definitely within the interval.

Comment: Note that the extreme value theorem only guarantees us that the minimum is reached; $\dot{a}(\alpha) = 0$ comes from [Fermat's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_theorem_(stationary_points)).